# pthread_cond_signal() doesn't wake up awaiting thread

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, pthreads, signals, wait

I'm testing pthread_cond_wait() if it could be woke up by signal function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
pthread_mutex_t _mutex(PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER);
pthread_cond_t  _cond (PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER);
void* producer(void*) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&_mutex);
    printf("producer wait() begins\n");
    pthread_cond_wait(&_cond, &_mutex);// hang here
    printf("producer wait() ends\n"); // not printed
    return NULL;
}
void* consumer(void*) {
    sleep(1);
    printf("consumer wait for lock\n");
    pthread_mutex_lock(&_mutex);
    printf("consumer signals\n");
    pthread_cond_signal(&_cond);
    sleep(2);
    return NULL;
}
int main() {
    pthread_t ptid, ctid;
    pthread_create(&ptid, NULL, producer, NULL);
    pthread_create(&ctid, NULL, consumer, NULL);
    pthread_join(ptid, NULL);
    pthread_join(ctid, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

It prints:

```
producer wait() begins
consumer wait for lock
consumer signals
```

It hangs there and never print `producer wait() end`. So what's happening here, why `pthread_cond_wait` is blocked?

Comment: Well, you never bother to unlock the mutex, so other thread is stuck waiting to lock the mutex.

Comment: Off topic but... since you've tagged this `c++` why not use [`std::condition_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) etc. rather than `pthread*`?

Comment: The producer thread won't come out of the `pthread_cond_wait` until it can latch the mutex (you know; the one that was released when you entered `pthread_cond_wait`). `consumer` never unlatches. And FYI, your producer is incorrect as well. Once you fix the first problem of unlocking the mutex you'll eventually realize the producer exits with the mutex still locked.  For your example it won't matter much, but as soon as you add more consumers and producers it is a recipe for an abandoned mutex and a full lockdown. Finally, this really isn't what cond-vars are for in the first place.

Comment: Consider switching to std::async, std::thread and std::conidition_variable. Using pthreads isn't necessary if you're in C++11 or later. Also read this, there are some extra conditions that you may not have checked : [C++ be aware of the traps of condition variables](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guidelines-be-aware-of-the-traps-of-condition-variables).